# std::set of template class without a specific definition

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I had the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class Value {
public:
    Value(std::string name, T value) : name(name), value(value) { }
    T const &value() throw() { return value }
    std::string const &name() throw() { return name }
private:
    std::string name;
    T value;
};
```

and then I wanted to do something like:

```
class Group {
public:
    Group(std::string name) : name(name) { }

    template<typename T>
    void add_value(std::string const &name, T const &val) throw() {
        Value<T> tmp(name, val);
        values.insert(tmp);
        return;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    std::set< Value<????> > values; // HERE BE MY QUESTION
}
```

Concretely, I want to store `Value` in its many template forms in the same std::set (like, having a `Value<int>` and a `Value<float>` stored in the same set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because `Value<T>` and `Value<X>` are completely and totally different and nearly unrelated types, like `int` and `string` (when `T != X`). In your case, they are extremely different because they actually store a `T` in themselves, which means that if the different `T`s are different sizes, the `Value<T>`s will be different sizes. (That's not *the* reason, it's just *a* reason.)

You may want to try using polymorphism, making `Value<T>` inherit from a base class so that you can store pointers to that base class which can be pointing to a `Value<T>` underneath, where `T` is any type your template supports.

Answer (score 1):

What Seth suggests is something like this:

```
class Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <typename T> class Value: public Base {
}

int main() {
  Set<Base*> base_set;
  base_set.add(new Value<int>(1));
  base_set.add(new Value<string>(1));
}
```